# Nested UIScrollView prevent bounce bubbling and allow parent paging when at end of list

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I want to recreate the same behavior as the stock weather app in iOS7.  Here is a screen shot:

[image: ios7 stock weather app]

The main screen is a UIScrollView that pages which contains a nested UIScrollView that scrolls left and right.

I've implemented this a bunch of ways but am not getting the experience quite right. If I just do something like this:

| UIScrollView
| ---> UICollectionView

When I swipe left and right fast it will cause the parent screen to bounce too causing you to see next page. I don't want this.  I have tried using all the delegates to try and disable the parent while the child is scrolling but this never behaved performant and felt clumsy.

I then nested the UICollection view in another UIScrollView and this stops the bouncing traveling up.  However when the UICollectionView settles at the end I should be able to scroll right and page the parent UIScrollView.  This does not happen.

All I can seem to do is have no bounce travel up to parent or allow parent paging when child is at either end.  How do I get both these behaviors?  Play with the stock iPhone weather app on iOS7 and you can see what I would like.  Thanks for any direction or help.

Comment: No idea what collection view does differently, but a scrollview embedded in another scrollview is the exact same behavior you experience in the weather app.

Answer (score 15):

Nest your scrollview in another scrollview that has bounces set to no.

```
Parent_scrollview
  container_scrollview->bounces no
    child_scrollview
```

The behavior of a scrollview is if it bounces, to find another scrollview that's higher up in the hierarchy and try to scroll it. If you put in a container scrollview that doesn't bounce, the parent will never get the child's bounce request.